# Java Getting an ASCII character set from a font and drawing each character separately on a white background?

Tags: java, image, ascii

Basically, I'm looking for a way to draw 255 images (ASCII character set) of a specific font. I would like each character to be drawn on a black background (white letter), and the image shouldn't be any bigger than the size of the character.

Comment: Nothing so far as I'm not even sure where to start with this to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first class you'll need to look at is the `java.awt.Font` class.  In order to specify a font, you need the name of the font, the point size, and the style of the font (NORMAL, BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE, etc.).

The next class you'll need to look at is the `java.awt.FontMetrics` class.  This is the class that will give you the size in pixels of your font.  The method `getStringBounds` returns a Rectangle that is the size, in pixels, of the text in the String.

Cycle over the 256 characters, converting the character to a string, and getting the string bounds.  Create a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` for each character, and draw the character on the `BufferedImage` by creating the graphics on the `BufferedImage`, and drawing the String of the character on the `BufferedImage`.  Write each `BufferedImage` out as a jpeg or png.

Comment: Thanks, I was familiar with these class' but wasn't sure of how to achieve what I was looking for.